# Split Finding Algorithms in Decision Trees

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, information-theory, greedy-algorithm

Given a Top-Down Induction of Decision Trees:

1. Select *best* decision attribute A for node (e.g. highest reduction in entropy)
2. For each value of A, create new descendant of node and sort training examples to leaves

When does this **Greedy Approach** become an **Exact Greedy Algorithm**?

Aren't we already considering all the possible splits on
all the attributes?